# Hide the fact that you are using Python to scrape a web site with Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, selenium-chromedriver

How could I hide the fact that I am using Python to scrape a web site with Chrome?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
priceretail_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type_0')  # Replace with the actual element locator.
priceretail_button.click()

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option0')  # Replace with the actual element locator.

# Create a Select object from the dropdown element.
select = Select(dropdown)

# Method 2: Select by option value (the "value" attribute of the <option> element).
select.select_by_value('Daily Prices')
date_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate')  # Replace with the actual element locator.

# Input a date into the date input field using the send_keys method.
date_input.send_keys('01/08/23')  # Replace with your desired date.
```

I tried to scrape a site with Chrome (https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/report_menu_web.aspx) for extracting data but the site is not working properly because of automation detection by Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add more information as to how the site is malfunctioning maybe provide some error logs, based on my experience I have had quite a few problems:

1. Make sure the driver you have installed is compatible with the browser version
2. Ensure the path you have provided of the driver is correct
3. If not add the driver to the source folder itself.
4. Additionaly there may be certain provisions that some Organizations (if you are working for one and this happens to be your work system) put forth that actively deter/block applications like crawlers or automation softwares because they can be categorized as spyware.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modify your code. Hope it will work for you as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
options.add_argument('--user-agent=YourUserAgentString')  


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
try:
    driver.get(url)
    priceretail_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type_0')))
    priceretail_button.click()

    dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option0')
    select = Select(dropdown)
    select.select_by_value('Daily Prices')

    date_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate')
    date_input.send_keys('01/08/23')


except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout: Element not found within the specified time.")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found on the page.")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```